# Unable to extract vmlinux from vmlinuz on Fedora 35

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to extract vmlinux from Fedora 35 standard vmlinuz file (vmlinuz-5.14.15-200.fc34.x86_64) using extract-vmlinux provided script:

```
/usr/src/kernels/5.14.15-200.fc34.x86_64/scripts/extract-vmlinux vmlinuz-5.14.15-200.fc34.x86_64 > vmlinux
 extract-vmlinux: Cannot find vmlinux.
```

Running file command I have:

```
file -bL ./vmlinuz-5.14.15-200.fc34.x86_64 
Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.14.15-200.fc34.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel02.iad2.fedoraproject.org) #1 SMP Wed Oct 27 15:53:30 UTC 2021, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0xA, Normal VGA
```

Question: why extract-vmlinux script  doesn't find vmlinux inside the file?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have all the tools used by `extract-vmlinuz`; as of 2022-01-16, these include (according to the [source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux), and excluding coreutils):

- `readelf` (so, `binutils`)
- `grep`
- The decompressor:

  - `gzip`
  - `xz`
  - `bzip2` (for your case!)
  - `unlzma`
  - `lzop`
  - `lz4`
  - `zstd`

Also, make sure `mktemp /tmp/vmlinuz-XXX` works for you.